# Possible to include XML doc (C#) in nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, documentation

We're currently creating an "automatic API self documentation" system which requires us to include the XML documentation from libraries (we put all our models into nuget packages as well, so every developer can use the same).

XML documentation file generation works like a charm, but when referencing the nuget packages, the XML files of the libraries are not put into the /bin directory of the actual service.

What is necessary to force nuget packages to also install the .xml-files for each .dll?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Are you saying that the XML documentation isn't included in the nuget package, or that it is, but it isn't copied to the bin directory of the application which references the nuget package? It's not normal for XML documentation to be copied to bin, so I wouldn't expect this to happen. However, that doesn't mean that the XML documentation isn't present in the nuget package.

Comment: It's not in the bin directory of the application, thats the problem.

We're creating everything via Gitlab CI/CD, but even when I create a small microservice to test the system locally, the XML files of the libraries we use are not in /bin.

Comment: Right, but they're not *expected* to be. Your question title asks whether it's possible to include them in the nuget package, which is different. Is the problem that they're not included in the nuget package, or is the question that you want to know how to then copy them to the bin directory? Those are two separate and different things.